# Ant: How to prevent the properties from being passed down to its descendant calls?

Tags: ant, properties

build.xml

```
<target name="main">
        <ant antfile="build-foo.xml" dir="${basedir}" target="foo"
            inheritAll="false" useNativeBasedir="true">
            <property name="messages" value="NOT_FOO_BAR"/>
        </ant>
</target>
```

build-foo.xml

```
<target name="foo">
        <property name="messages" value="FOO"/>
        <ant antfile="build-bar.xml" dir="${basedir}" target="bar"
            inheritAll="false" useNativeBasedir="true">

        </ant>
</target>
```

build-bar.xml

```
<target name="bar">
    <property name="messages" value="BAR"/>
    <echo message="messages = ${messages}"/>
</target>
```

Tried:

```
    ant -buildfile build-foo.xml foo

        the messages is BAR, as expected.

    ant -buildfile build.xml main

        the messages is NOT_FOO_BAR.
```

The properties from main is passed multi-level down, even if it is not desired in build-foo.xml: inheritAll=false.

How to prevent the properties from being passed down to its descendant calls? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From [ant manual ant task](http://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/ant.html) :

> You can also set properties in the new project from the old project by
>   **using nested property tags**. **These properties are always passed to
>   the new project** and any project created in that project **regardless
>   of the setting of inheritAll**. This allows you to parameterize your
>   subprojects.

instead :

```
<target name="main">
 <ant antfile="build-foo.xml" dir="${basedir}" target="foo"
  inheritAll="false" useNativeBasedir="true"/>
 <property name="messages" value="NOT_FOO_BAR"/>
</target>
```

meets your expections.

Comment: I see, so there is no way to interrupt the property passing. But there should be an attribute to stop that.

Comment: @Dave There IS a way, simply avoid nested properties inside ant task, but use property task outside and ant task with attribute inheritAll=false ;-)